# Edit env file in pipeline

Tags: symfony, docker, environment-variables, continuous-deployment, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a symfony skeleton project, and I use the .env file for storing the environment variables.

Inside the Dockerfile, I run `composer install`, but it creates a .env file. From my pipeline environment variables I want to edit the .env file. What is the best approach to do that?

Delete the .env and create my own? Or is there a way to edit the .env file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bash redirection` to append values to your .env file.

`echo ENV_VARAIBLE=value > .env` - Use this if .env doesn't exist, (op.a. it overwrites existing .env)

`echo ENV_VARIABLE_2=value2 >> .env` - Use this to append variable to existing .env file.

More: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89386/what-is-symbol-and-in-unix-linux

A lot more: http://www.catonmat.net/blog/bash-one-liners-explained-part-three/